# How to access a specific part of a string and replace it after processing in php

Tags: php

I have a string of such like

```
$text_string = 'Every thing must be done in time. So,It is not a good thing to be
                so late. What are the Rules of This Process are prominent in this
                video [VIDEO]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yseAuiSl[/VIDEO]. So,
                It will be more sensible if you watch a tutorial here
                [VIDEO]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xyxmu6_underwater[/VIDEO]
                It is much more explanatory. These are the Rules of Thumb.'
```

I need to get each `[VIDEO] .... [/VIDEO]` and then pass it to a function (I have created that function on my own) that will convert it to its according embed code for example

```
[VIDEO]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yseAuiSl[/VIDEO]
```

will be converted to

```
<iframe width="680" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yseAuiSl" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then I need to replace the `[VIDEO] .... [/VIDEO]` with its embed code. So, How I can loop through the whole string and get each `[VIDEO] ... [/VIDEO]` tag one by one and after processing replace it with its embed code?

Comment: @Charlie that is only for replace, but first I need to get the whole VIDEO tag, process it through a function, then replace it with its output. So, How can I get out each VIDEO tag from string?

Comment: use `preg_match()` -> processing -> `preg_replace()`. good luck !

Comment: google: php replace within tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Spending a lot of time and with the help of Stackoverflow guys, I have got the solution.

```
$text_string = 'Every thing must be done in time. So,It is not a good thing to be
                so late. What are the Rules of This Process are prominent in this
                video [VIDEO]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yseAuiSl[/VIDEO]. So,
                It will be more sensible if you watch a tutorial here
                [VIDEO]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xyxmu6_underwater[/VIDEO]
                It is much more explanatory. These are the Rules of Thumb.'
```

Here is the function that will convert my link to embed code

```
function convert_to_embed($matches) {
  $link = $matches[1];

  // All the Function Process

  return $embed;
}
```

Here I am using `preg_replace_callback` function that will process each of the VIDEO tag one by one and the function will convert and replace the VIDEO Tag with its embed code.

```
 $finalized_string  = preg_replace_callback('/\[VIDEO\](.+?)\[\/VIDEO\]/i', "convert_to_embed", $text_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace('/\[VIDEO\](.+?)\[\/VIDEO\]/i', '<iframe width="680" height="450" src="\\1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $text_string);
```

Comment: Although, I have to process the link between the VIDEO tags, but I got an idea from your preg_replace. I am going to use preg_replace_callback. Thanks for the REGEX.

Answer (score 0):

in my idea:
You are going to need to iterate through the words and find the starting and ending positions of the VIDEO;
some code:

```
$text_string = 'Every thing must be done in time. So,It is not a good thing to be
                so late. What are the Rules of This Process are prominent in this
                video [VIDEO]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yseAuiSl[/VIDEO]. So,
                It will be more sensible if you watch a tutorial here
                [VIDEO]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xyxmu6_underwater[/VIDEO]
                It is much more explanatory. These are the Rules of Thumb.'

$start = '[VIDEO]';
$end = '[/VIDEO]';
$words_array  = explode(' ',$text_string);
$words = array_flip($words_array);

//Then you can check for video element with:
$word_pos = 0;
foreach($words as $the_word){
$word_pos++;
if ($the_word == $start){
$start_point = $word_pos;
}

if ($the_word == $end){
$end_point = $word_pos;
}
}
$video_link = echo substr($text_string,$start_point,$end_point);
```

The code is only to share the concept I have got for this..!